# Laravel: foreach not interating properly?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 querys in Laravel like this

```
$topRespects = UserStats::with('user')->orderBy('Respect', 'DESC')->get();

$topReferrals = User::orderBy('user_referrals', 'DESC')->get();
```

For example, this loop with show the content 10 times.

```
@foreach ($topReferrals->take(10) as $user)
@endforeach
```

If I go with this loop, it will only show it 8 times?

```
@foreach ($topRespects->take(10) as $userStats)
    @foreach ($userStats->user as $user)

    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

If I take more, such as 12 say, it shows 9, if I take 15 it shows the full 10, but surely it shouldn't work like this? It's hard to know when it will work correctly and incorrectly.

Why is loop 2 acting so out of the ordinary and how do I fix it?

Comment: Where in the loop(s) is the content?

Comment: I suppose some variables are somehow overwritten, that changes loop behaviour.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir the loops are the foreaches?

Comment: Where is the HTML content that shows up x times?

Comment: I decided not to show it for minimal example, even when just printing 'hello world' it still prints the same amount of times, so the content is not the problem here.

Comment: Is the content in the outer (`$topRespects`) or the inner (`$userStats->user`) loop?

Comment: When running the top loop it shows all 10, the inner loop `$userStats->user` brings the problem.

Comment: How many combined users does `$topRespects->take(10)` have? `$topRespects->take(10)->pluck('user')->collapse()->count()`

Comment: It has 8 users.

Comment: So your loops are working correctly?

Comment: They are working correctly, but its returning 8 instead of 10...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166163/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-0b9ff4fb).

Comment: It's unclear what `$userStats` is here

Comment: `$userStats` is part of the `$topRespects->take(10)` array, see the first @foreach.

Comment: Why won't you just limit the query? ‘$topReferrals = User::orderBy('user_referrals', 'DESC')->limit(10)->get();‘

Answer (score 0):

you can try **array_chunk()** method of laravel.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Model::take(10);
```

this is a model method, try using it in the eloquent query, not on the object returned from the query.

```
User::orderBy('user_referrals', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();
```